# can not clear data on the screen after logout React Native

Tags: react-native

after logout, I log in with another account but the data is still there I have to switch to another screen before going back to that screen to get new data.
this is button logout

```
      <Button
          title={'Logout'}
          style={styles.marginButton}
          onPress={async () => {
            navigation.navigate('Login');
            await AsyncStorage.clear();
          }}>
      </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear asyncStorage before navigate to Login maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the storage data before navigating so place the await AsyncStorage.clear() before navigating

```
onPress={async () => {
       await AsyncStorage.clear();
       navigation.navigate('Login');
    
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

use removeItem.

```
AsyncStorage.removeItem("userDetails");
AsyncStorage.removeItem("authToken");
```

replace userDetails & authToken with your variables.